# Using default generated copy constructor with Q_DECLARE_METATYPE

Tags: c++, qt

Suppose I have this custom class

```
struct Analytics : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT

  public:
  int a  = 12;

  Analytics(const Analytics& a) {
  }

  Analytics(){
  }

};

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Analytics)
```

The above works fine. However I have to supply my own copy constructor.
I tried this using the default generated copy contructor however I get the error

struct Analytics : public QObject
    {
      Q_OBJECT

```
  public:
  int a  = 12;

  Analytics(const Analytics& a) = default;

  Analytics(){
  }

};

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Analytics)
```

this is the error that I get

```
  5: error: call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor of 'Analytics'
                return new (where) T(*static_cast<const T*>(t));
```

Is it possible to use Q_DECLARE_METATYPE with default generated copy constructor.

Answer (score 1):

From documentation:

> QObject has neither a copy constructor nor an assignment operator.
>   This is by design. Actually, they are declared, but in a private
>   section with the macro Q_DISABLE_COPY(). In fact, all Qt classes
>   derived from QObject (direct or indirect) use this macro to declare
>   their copy constructor and assignment operator to be private. The
>   reasoning is found in the discussion on Identity vs Value on the Qt
>   Object Model page.

So you can't copy QObjects and classes derived from QObject. If you want to use signals and slots mechanism with QObjects, use pointers instead.

Comment: But if I add a copy constructor and pass an object on stack (not a ptr) via signal then the slot receives a copy am I correct ?

Comment: Just noticed that Analytis is struct, not class. If you'll define Analytics as class you'll get an error that copy constructor is private. QObjects not support copying by design, don't do this. Also you don't need to use Q_DECLARE_METATYPE for classes derived from QObject. Why do you want to do `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Analytics)` ?